# Power BI Data Previews

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have this client who wants me to work on his PowerBI file. The problem I have is when I enter Transform page, I am being asked for credentials and the preview is basically blank. Is there a way to remedy this? Would be asking the client to disable background refresh on the file prior to sharing it help? I can probably make do with the data view but in the event that client wants me to make some query level changes, I need to be prepared to make those edits then upload the file so my client can apply the query level transformations

Further context. What I need to achieve right now is develop SQL queries to alleviate the load time it takes the report to complete the refresh since the current setup the client implemented is basically loading entire tables from the server then filtering the results via PowerQuery.

Comment: The client will need to add you and give you permissions to read from the data source.

Comment: And read up on Query Folding.  It may not be necessary to rewrite the queries in SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding